# Why I am getting Gas estimation error in remix

Tags: solidity

I have the following code for a flash loan in remix:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.10;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


import {
  IPoolAddressesProvider
} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import { IPool } from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol";
import { IFlashLoanSimpleReceiver } from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/contracts/flashloan/interfaces/IFlashLoanSimpleReceiver.sol";
import { IERC20 } from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";
import { SafeMath } from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/SafeMath.sol";

interface IFaucet {
    function mint(
        address _token,
        uint256 _amount
    ) external;
}

abstract contract FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase is IFlashLoanSimpleReceiver {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  IPoolAddressesProvider public immutable override ADDRESSES_PROVIDER;
  IPool public immutable override POOL;
  IFaucet public immutable FAUCET;

  constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider provider, IFaucet faucet) {
    ADDRESSES_PROVIDER = provider;
    POOL = IPool(provider.getPool());
    FAUCET = faucet;
  }

//   constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider provider) {
//     ADDRESSES_PROVIDER = provider;
//     POOL = IPool(provider.getPool());
//   }
}


/** 
    !!!
    Never keep funds permanently on your FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase contract as they could be 
    exposed to a 'griefing' attack, where the stored funds are used by an attacker.
    !!!
 */
contract MySimpleFlashLoanV3 is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    IERC20 sellToken;
    IERC20 buyToken;
    address spender;
    address payable swapTarget;
    bytes swapCallData;
    address payable owner;

    constructor(IPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider,IFaucet _faucet) FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(_addressProvider,_faucet) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    function widthdrawAmount() internal {
        require(owner == msg.sender,"Only for owner");
        owner.transfer(10);
    }
    function fillQuote(
    )
        internal // Must attach ETH equal to the `value` field from the API response.
    {
        // Track our balance of the buyToken to determine how much we've bought.
        uint256 boughtAmount = buyToken.balanceOf(address(this));

        // Give `spender` an infinite allowance to spend this contract's `sellToken`.
        // Note that for some tokens (e.g., USDT, KNC), you must first reset any existing
        // allowance to 0 before being able to update it.
        require(sellToken.approve(spender, type(uint256).max));
        // Call the encoded swap function call on the contract at `swapTarget`,
        // passing along any ETH attached to this function call to cover protocol fees.
        (bool success,) = swapTarget.call{value: msg.value}(swapCallData);
        require(success, 'SWAP_CALL_FAILED');
        // Refund any unspent protocol fees to the sender.
        // msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

        // // Use our current buyToken balance to determine how much we've bought.
        boughtAmount = buyToken.balanceOf(address(this)) - boughtAmount;
        // emit BoughtTokens(sellToken, buyToken, boughtAmount);
    }
    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    )
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {

        //
        // This contract now has the funds requested.
        // Your logic goes here.
        //

        fillQuote();
        
        // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
        // the flashloaned amounts + premiums.
        // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay asset: 0xA2025B15a1757311bfD68cb14eaeFCc237AF5b43
        // assetprovider: 0xc4dCB5126a3AfEd129BC3668Ea19285A9f56D15D
        // faucet: 0x1ca525Cd5Cb77DB5Fa9cBbA02A0824e283469DBe
        // these amounts.
        // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        uint amountOwed = amount.add(premium);
        // FAUCET.mint(asset,1000000000000);
        IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwed);
        // widthdrawAmount();
        return true;
    }

    function executeFlashLoan(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        IERC20 _sellToken,
        // The `buyTokenAddress` field from the API response.
        IERC20 _buyToken,
        // The `allowanceTarget` field from the API response.
        address allowanceTarget,
        // The `to` field from the API response.
        address payable _to,
        // The `data` field from the API response.
        bytes calldata _data
    ) public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        sellToken = _sellToken;
        buyToken = _buyToken;
        spender = allowanceTarget;
        swapTarget = _to;
        // swapCallData = _data;

        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            receiverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }
}
```

I am new to solidity, may anyone tell me why I am getting gas estimation error in remix ?

Comment: Gas estimation fail is message you that your transaction will be reverted. If you want to know Why this happens, and where is an error - you need to provide manual gas limit and execute transaction onchain. This will get you actual failed transaction, and you will be able to debug this with tools like Etherscan, Tenderly or gethDebugTrace

Comment: I have given very high gas limit like `555555` still it doesn't work.

Comment: Check all the URLs you have imported, see if those code exist in those locations.

Comment: You need to make tx, even if this tx will fail, later you can debug and find revert reasons